# subprocess.call() works differently from script and interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Want to run a binary from the python script by the following code:

```
def runner(output_file):
  result = 1

  try:
      image_name = re.sub(r'\..*', '.png', output_file)
      args = ['dot', output_file, '-Tpng', '-o', image_name]
      result = subprocess.call(args)

      if(result == 0):
          print('Graph is rendered to {0}'.format(image_name))

  except:
      print('ERROR: Cannot run DOT. Please check your PATH')

  return result
```

When I call this function it returns `0` and everything seems to be OK, but **there is no file produced**.

When I do the same from Python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> output_file = 'out.dot'
>>> image_name = 'out.png'
>>> args = ['dot', output_file, '-Tpng', '-o', image_name]
>>> subprocess.call(args)
```

**file is produced successfully**.

I tried to set an incorrect name, and got an error in script (as expected). Calling `pwd` from script gave me a correct directory. Call with hardcoded values did the same as calling with variables.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you should run with shell=True?

Comment: Try `print args` before invoking `subprocess.call`

Comment: @thefourtheye `['dot', 'out.dot', '-Tpng', '-o', 'out.png']`

Comment: How (And under which directory) did you run the script?

Comment: @RedBaron it is the same directory the `out.dot` is placed in both cases script and interpreter.
I run it: `python script.py`

Comment: @bernie I did not succeed to find output file at all.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik it stuck in `dot`, like I run it without arguments.

Comment: Also, although it does not appear to present an issue here, there is no good reason to be using a bare `except:` clause. I recommend not using that unless you have a good reason to do so as it can hide exceptions you're not expecting.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik What exactly should work better with `shell=True`, especially when a list is used for `args`?

Comment: @bernie Examining the output can as well done with `.call()`: it is just output on the consople and clearly visible.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik No. Do *not* use `shell=True`, especially with a list of arguments. When `shell=True` the first element of the list is taken as the whole command-line, all other elements are passed as options *to the shell*. This clearly is *not* what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers that *might* help.

*First*: In my experience `args = [...]` is error prone.

```
shlex.split('dot {0} -Tpng -o {1}'.format(input_file, image_name))
```

is generally more robust. However it requires you to escape spaces in file names correctly...

*Second*: Do you have your input and output files reversed in your args? Or are the variables just named poorly?

*Third*: Please, for the zen of python and the sake of your own sanity don't do the [diaper antipattern](http://mike.pirnat.com/2009/05/09/the-diaper-pattern-stinks/) e.g. `except:`

*Fourth*: Relying on `$PATH` and/or using a non-absolute path to binary is bound to break at some point - use the full `/path/to/dot` as your first argument.

Comment: I completely disagree about the robustness of the `shlex` approach. You have to take care, but if you do so, things work much better - especially, as you say, with file names and their escaping.

Comment: shlex.split() doesn't help. How do you think should it be used?